# Variance of sine and cosine of a random variable

Tags: variance

Suppose $X$ is a random variable drawn from a normal distribution with mean $E$ and variance $V$. How could I calculate variance of $\sin(X)$ and $\cos(X)$?

(I thought the question was simple and tried to do a search, but did not find any good answer.)

What if there is no assumption about the distribution of $X$, and only sample mean and variance are provided?

Comment: Both variables are bounded in $[-1, 1]$ so one can [show](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45588/variance-of-a-bounded-random-variable) that the variance is $\le \frac{2^2}{4} = 1$.

Comment: That's an interesting point, might be helpful so I'll keep it in mind. However, I would like to know an exact formula/procedure if it is possible.

Comment: You can always write down the relevant integrals and feed them to a CAS.  Mathematica told me $\operatorname{Var}(\sin(X)) = \frac{1}{2} (1-e^{-2\sigma^2}\cos(2\mu))$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\cos(X)) = -e^{-\sigma^2} \cos^2\mu + \frac{1}{2}(1+e^{-2\sigma^2} \cos(2\mu))$.

Comment: @angryavian: That particular bound is rather trivial here, since $\operatorname{Var}(Y) = E[Y^2] - E[Y]^2 \le E[Y^2]  \le E[1] = 1$.  Indeed, Popoviciu's inequality for random variables bounded between $m$ and $M$ becomes trivial (but still sharp) when $m = -M$.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks a lot for the answer! That really fits what I actually want.

Comment: @NateEldredge Or, without an integral (Mathematica does (simple) expectations): ``Expectation[ (Sin[X] - 
   Expectation[ Sin[X], 
    X \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]])^2, 
 X \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[\[Mu], \[Sigma]]]``

Comment: (You may want to add ``FullSimplify[ExpToTrig[   ]]`` around that to have a representation in terms of $\sin,\cos$ instead of exponentials)

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2134801/compute-e-sin-x-if-x-is-normally-distributed

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What is below is for $\mu=0$ (and variance renamed $\sigma^2$). Then $\mathbb{E}[\sin X]=0$, and you have
$$
\operatorname{Var} \sin X = \mathbb{E}[\sin^2 X]
= \frac{1}{2}\left(1-\mathbb{E}[\cos 2X]\right) 
$$
and
$$
\mathbb{E}[\cos 2X] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty  (-1)^k\frac{2^{2k}}{(2k)!} \mathbb{E}[X^{2k}]
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k\frac{2^{2k}}{(2k)!} \sigma^{2k} (2k-1)!!
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{2^{k}\sigma^{2k}}{k!} = e^{-2\sigma^{2}}
$$
and therefore
$$
\operatorname{Var} \sin X = \boxed{\frac{1-e^{-2\sigma^2}}{2}}
$$
You can deal with the variance of $\cos X$ in a similar fashion *(but you now have to substract a non-zero $\mathbb{E}[\cos X]^2$),* especially recalling that $\mathbb{E}[\cos^2 X] = 1- \mathbb{E}[\sin^2 X]$.

---

Now, for non-zero mean $\mu$, you have
$$
\sin(X-\mu) = \sin X\cos \mu - \cos X\sin\mu 
$$
(and similarly for $\cos(X-\mu)$)
Since $X-\mu$ is a zero-mean Gaussian with variance $\sigma^2$, we have computed the mean and variance of $\sin(X-\mu)$, $\cos(X-\mu)$ already. You can use this with the above trigonometric identities to find those of $\cos X$ and $\sin X$. (it's a bit cumbersome, but not too hard.)

---

*Without knowing anything about the distribution of $X$, I don't think there's much you can do.*

Comment: I might have missed something, but could you tell me why $Var sin(X) = E[sin^2 X]$ ? Also why does the result not contain anything related to mean or variance of $X$?

Comment: @HùngPhạm Oh, my bad, I did it for mean $0$ and variance $1$. Let me fix that.

Comment: I think you'd need to consider $\mathbb E(sin^2x)-[\mathbb E(sinx)]^2$

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar It becomes a bit more complicated than that, actually.

Comment: @HùngPhạm I added the variance. Trying to see if this approach is amenable to a non-zero mean as well without too much pain..

Comment: I think the complication arises from the fact that one cant simply take $\mathbb E(sin^2x) = sin^2\bar x$. You have to consider the non-linearity. Maybe a 2nd order 2nd moment approach?

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar The main issue with the non-zero mean is the fact that the central moments don't have a nice expression inside the series. So a way to circumvent this is needed.

Comment: Perhaps a 2nd order Taylor expansion? This is what we typically do in Reliability analysis. We actually truncate it to first order.

Comment: @SharatVChandrasekhar Or just $\sin(X-\mu) = \sin X\cos \mu - \cos X\sin\mu$ :)

Comment: This answer does look sufficient to me. I will go with this answer and complete the rest. If it's too cumbersome, I guess I will consider using a 2nd (or 1st) order Taylor representation. Thank you a lot and also @SharatVChandrasekhar

Comment: @HungPham Glad this helped.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a general formulation using [the law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) that can be applied to other functions too. For specific calculations with $\sin$ and $\cos$ here though, I would say Clement C.'s answer is better!

The mean of $\color{blue}{h(X)}$ (for some function $h$) would be given by the integral
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\color{blue}{h(x)}f_X(x)\, dx,$$
where $f_X$ is the probability density function of $X$.

The second moment would be found similarly as $$\mathbb{E}\left[(h(X))^2\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\color{blue}{(h(x)^2)}f_X(x)\, dx.$$

Once you know the first two moments here, you can calculate the variance using $\mathrm{Var}(Z) = \mathbb{E}[Z^2] - (\mathbb{E}[Z])^2$.

Replace $h(x)$ with $\cos x$ for the corresponding expectations for $\cos X$, and similarly with $\sin x$.

If the distribution of $X$ is not known, we cannot generally compute the exact mean and variance of $h(X)$. However, you may want to see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_expansions_for_the_moments_of_functions_of_random_variables) for some approximations that could be used. Some useful ones for you may be that if $X$ has mean $\mu_X$ and variance $\sigma^2_X$, then
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X)]\approx h(\mu_X) + \dfrac{h''(\mu_X)}{2}\sigma_X^2$$
and
$$\mathrm{Var}(h(X))\approx (h'(\mu_X)^2)\sigma^2_X +  \dfrac{1}{2}(h''(\mu_X))^2 \sigma^4_X.$$

Answer (score 1):

$\cos^2(x) = \frac{\cos(2x)+1}2$, which averages out to $\frac12$. So as the variance of $X$ goes to infinity, the variance of $\cos(X)$ goes to $\frac12$, assuming the distribution of $X$ is "well-behaved". The lower bound is $0$ (the variance can be made arbitrarily small by choosing the variance of $X$ to be small enough), and as @angryavian says, the upper bound is $1$. Since $|\cos(x)| \leq 0$, and the inequality is strict for all but a measure zero set, the variance of $\cos(X)$ is less than the variance of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the kind answer you are looking for, but you can compute this empirically pretty easily via [probabilistic programming](http://www.probabilistic-programming.org/wiki/Home). Here is an example with Python and [pymc3](https://docs.pymc.io/), taking $E=0.75$ and $V=0.25^2$:

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np

with pm.Model() as model:
    x = pm.Normal('x', mu=0.75, sd=0.25)
    y = pm.Deterministic('y', np.sin(x))
    trace = pm.sample(10000)

pm.plot_posterior(trace)
pm.summary(trace)
```

This snippet will produce a plot showing the distribution of $X$ and $Y=\sin(X)$

[image: posterior]

And this table, which shows mean, standard deviation, bounds for the 95% confidence interval, and some diagnostics to make sure the results are reliable (they are):

```
       mean        sd  mc_error   hpd_2.5  hpd_97.5        n_eff      Rhat
x  0.747098  0.248358  0.003078  0.269450  1.240856  7756.202193  0.999998
y  0.658854  0.178794  0.002208  0.322414  0.980199  7731.781691  1.000049
```

Comment: Actually, I thought of something similar to this previously. I did not follow this approach for 2 reasons: a) I did not know if this was a well-known, trivial problem that could be deterministically solved or not; b) I want to plug this calculation into a fast program, so sampling a lot # of points might slow it down especially when I repeat the operation many times. But nevertheless, your answer is still very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here I will call the expected value $\mu$ and the variance $\sigma^2.$
\begin{align}
\operatorname E(\sin X) = {} & \operatorname E\left( \frac{e^{iX} - e^{-iX}}{2i} \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \operatorname E \left( \frac{e^{i(\mu+\sigma Z)}-e^{-i(\mu+\sigma Z)}}{2i} \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & \frac 1 {2i} \left( e^{i\mu} \operatorname E( e^{i\sigma Z}) - e^{-i\mu} \operatorname E(e^{-i\sigma Z})  \right).
\end{align}

$$
\text{And } \operatorname E(e^{i\sigma Z}) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{i\sigma z} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} \, dz. \tag 1
$$

The exponent is
\begin{align}
-\tfrac 1 2 z^2 + i\sigma z = {} & -\tfrac 1 2 \left( z^2 - 2i \sigma z \right) \\[8pt]
= {} & -\tfrac 1 2 \left( z^2 - 2i\sigma z - \sigma^2 \right) - \tfrac 1 2 \sigma^2 \\[8pt]
= {} & -\tfrac 1 2 \left( z-i\sigma \right)^2 - \tfrac 1 2 \sigma^2
\end{align}
The integral on line $(1)$ above becomes
$$
e^{-i\sigma^2/2} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(z-i\sigma)^2/2} \, dz.
$$
The integral is equal to $1,$ and so the question is: how do we know *that*?

The integral is equal to $\displaystyle \lim_{A\to\infty} \int_{-A}^{+A} \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(z-i\sigma)^2/2} \, dz.$

So we consider
$$
\left( \int_{+A}^{-A} +\int_{-A}^{-A-\sigma i} + \int_{-A-\sigma i}^{+A-\sigma i} + \int_{+A-\sigma i}^{+A} \right) \frac 1 {\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-z^2/2} \, dz
$$
and observe that

- the first integral above approaches $1$ as $A\to+\infty,$ and
- the second and fourth integrals are easily seen to approach $0,$ and
- the third integral is the one whose limit we seek, and
- the sum of the four integrals is $0$ because we are integrating along a path that returns to its starting point and the function being integrated has no sigularities in the interior of the surrounded region.

We conclude that $\operatorname E(e^{i\sigma Z}) = e^{-i\sigma^2/2}.$ Similarly $\operatorname E(e^{-i\sigma Z}) = e^{+i\sigma^2/2}.$