# Compute $Var(\sin(X))$ when X is normally distributed

Tags: probability, gaussian

What will be the $Var(\sin(X))$ when $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: Does this help?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121914/variance-of-sine-and-cosine-of-a-random-variable

Comment: For $\mu \neq 0$ this won't work. I wonder if there is some nice closed form solution.

Comment: Have you encountered Characteristic function before? The above link should be quite useful since the only thing you need to do is find $E(sin X)$, which can be done using cf

Answer (score 0):

It's:
$$\frac12(1-e^{-\sigma^2})(1+e^{-\sigma^2}\cos 2\mu )\qquad (*)$$

Note that in the special case $\mu=0$, this simplifies to the answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3121924/401952).

You can derive this as follows.  The characteristic function of a standard normal is:
$$E e^{itZ} = e^{-t^2/2}$$
However, from the identity $e^{ix} = i \sin x + \cos x$ and linearity of the expectation, this means:
$$i E\sin (tZ) + E\cos (tZ) = e^{-t^2/2}$$
implying $E \sin tZ = 0$  (which was obvious by symmetry of $Z$) and:
$$E \cos (tZ) = e^{-t^2/2}$$ which was less obvious.

Now, it's just trigonometric identities.  First, by the usual identity for the sine of sums, we have:
$$\sin(\mu + \sigma Z) = \sin \mu \cos(\sigma Z) + \sin (\sigma Z) \cos \mu$$
and therefore, for $X = \mu + \sigma Z$, we have:
$$E \sin X = \sin \mu\, E \cos(\sigma Z) + \cos \mu\, E \sin(\sigma Z)
= \sin \mu \times e^{-\sigma^2/2} + \cos \mu \times 0$$
Second, we have
\begin{align}
\sin^2(\mu + \sigma Z)
&= (1 - \cos [2(\mu + \sigma Z)])/2  
& \hbox{as $\cos 2\theta = 1-2\sin^2\theta$}\\
&= (1 - \cos (2\mu) \cos(2\sigma Z) + \sin(2\mu)\sin(2\sigma Z))/2
& \hbox{identity for $\cos (\alpha+\beta)$}\\
\end{align}
and therefore, we have
$$E (\sin X)^2
= \left(1 - \cos(2\mu)e^{-2\sigma^2} + 0\right)/2
$$

This gives:
\begin{align}
\mbox{Var}(\sin X) &= \left(1-e^{-2\sigma^2}\cos(2\mu)\right)/2 - [e^{-\sigma^2/2}\sin \mu]^2 \\
&= \left(1-e^{-2\sigma^2}\cos(2\mu)\right)/2 - e^{-\sigma^2}(1-\cos(2\mu))/2
\end{align}
with the second equality following from $\cos 2\theta = 1 - 2\sin^2 \theta$.

Factoring this gives the expression (*) above.